# How do you use Notepad++ regex pipe | for strings longer than one character?

Tags: regex, notepad++, pipe

I'm trying to get notepad++ to regex find all instances of "abc" and "def" in the following sentence:

> The abc went to the def.

None of the following syntaxes seem to work:

- abc|def
- [abc|def]
- (abc)|(def)
- (abc|def)

NOTE: "[a|d]" matches any instance of "a" or "d" when I tested

Comment: [a|d] doesn't mean what you think it does, it means "match any of a, d, or |". [ad] would do the same thing, but that's different from a|d.

Comment: What I mean is, the | character inside [a|d] isn't actually doing anything, it's just saying that it's also ok to match "|". That's not what you were trying to do. Because Notepad++ doesn't support using the | character to mean "one of", what you're trying to do will be impossible.

Comment: How will I be able to search SQL query typed within " any sql query " even if the query is multilined. I tried ["][^\n]["] for single line and ["]*["] for multiline but in case of multiline it ignores the second quote in same line and ends at next line at ramdom quote position ... I need help here and I am finding it using Notepad++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upgrade to Notepad++ v6.  From the changelog: "PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) is supported."  I've verified that | works in regex search when using Notepad++ v6.

Answer (score 24):

<strike>It's nothing special about "longer than one character", Notepad++ doesn't support the | character in regex. Not even "a|d" works. See [the regex help page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators).</strike> Version 6.1.1 of Notepad++ now supports `|`.

I'd suggest using an editor with a proper regex implementation like [gvim](http://www.vim.org/) or [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/).

Comment: The latest version as of today (Notepad 10.1.1) supports | in RegEx

Comment: @DragosToader ...and yet, you don't bother answering the op's question??

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy The answer for Notepad 10.1.1 is to search for (abc)|(def)

Answer (score 1):

Inside a character set declaration (`[…]`) only the characters `\`, `]` and `-` are special characters with the special functions of escaping the next character, closing the character set declaration and marking a character range (only if not written at the begin or end), respectively. Any other character is interpretet as a plain character.

So is your `|` in `[a|d]` which means that `[a|d]` describes any of the characters `a`, `|` or `d` and not just `a` or `d` like `a|d` does.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, which is how I landed here.  Since it's a notepad++ deficiency, we can make do by using Powershell.  In your case, simply run a Select-String:

```
`ss abc,def filename`
```

If on Unix then you have other tools like grep of course.

I recognize you wanted a solution for notepad++, and so do I, but sometimes you have to make do.

Answer (score 1):

The `|` should work now.
Thanks to the Regex improvements in Notepad++

```
abc|def
```

```
(abc)|(def)
```