# How to find different words like a or b in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++'s Regular Expressions don't support symbol |.So how can I find different words like a or b in notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

Its working at my end, I'm using this:
`c[a|o]t` to search for cat OR cot

Do you have the latest version, 5.4.3?

Comment: `[a|o]` is a character class. Try to search "bus" or "bills".

Comment: yeah i guess thats right -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820740/how-do-you-use-notepad-regex-pipe-for-strings-longer-than-one-character

Comment: With Notepad++ 6.3:  Regular expression (RE) searching for `c[a|o]t` will find **cat** OR **cot** as said above. It will also find **c|t** as the `|` is just another character when between square braces. RE searching for `c(a|o)t` will only find the **cat** OR **cot**. REs to search for bus or bills include `bus|bills`, `b(u|ill)s` and even `b[uil]+s` but this last will also find **buus** and **bilius** and any other combination of `u`, `l` and `i` between `b` and `s`.

Comment: great feature of notepad+. just set 'search mode' in modal window as 'regular expression'