# Regex OR in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to find all following instances in notepad++

```
action421
action732
action983
```

but ignore all other `actionXXX` combinations.

I'm looking for a regex similar to `action(421)|(732)|(983)` but it doesn't work. What regex would?

Does [notepad++ regex engine](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html) even have an `OR` operator?

Comment: The notepad++ regex engine as of version 10.1.1 has an OR operator.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like Don Ho added the RegEx OR | operator to the Notepad++ native `Find` in the
latest version of Notepad (ver. 6.1.1).
Download Notepad 6.1.1 from [here](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.1.html)

Install Notepad 6.1.1, then go to 
Search->Find
Find what: `action(421|732|983)`
Search Mode: `(*) Regular Expression`

Click on the `Find Next` button

Comment: Full regex was added by me in 6.0.  It's gone through several rounds of improvements and other contributions (mainly F.R. Boyer), and is pretty much stable, solid and does-what-you-expect in 6.3.1.

Answer (score 10):

**It is now possible in Notepad >= 10.1.1.** According to [Dragos Toader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78706/dragos-toader): "The latest version as of today (Notepad 10.1.1) supports | in RegEx"

== original answer below ==

It's not possible in Notepad++. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820740/how-do-you-use-notepad-regex-pipe-for-strings-longer-than-one-character/820762#820762)

But your regex is not correct. This one would work: `action(421|732|983)` if Notepad++ supported the `|` in regex.

Comment: Hmm... This doesn't seem to work either!? Not in my Notepad++ anyway... **edit** @Jonathan does this work for you??

Comment: It doesn't work - I think that would find combinations of the sort of action4273283 and action4213983  ...

Comment: No the `(` and `)` mean a group. The `|` means `OR`. In PHP this regex works perfectly. In Notepad++ I can't get it to work. I've updated the answer with an example in PHP that works.

Comment: I find this very strange: http://screencast.com/t/bL13glMp1K8Z **edit** Better screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/fSmS4ZRmNDt

Comment: Updated answer. The important thing though is that you remember the right regex ;) because they are very very often very very useful! And supported by every single half decent language both front-end and back-end. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html for quick help.

Comment: @Rudie if you post images, please upload them there where they will be not deleted few weeks/months later

Comment: The latest version as of today (Notepad 10.1.1) supports | in RegEx

Comment: @Xerkus Good point. I saw that too. My bad. [I found one of the screenshots.](http://content.screencast.com/users/RudieDirkx/folders/Jing/media/08647ed9-f24d-49f2-9455-6dbcebb06c19/2011-05-07_2037.png)

Comment: @DragosToader: Where can I find v10.1.1? The latest version of Notepad++ is 6.1.2 @ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [regex helper plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppregexhelper/) for Notepad++, but that is more for regex development than replace, but if you just want to find, I think this plugin can be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I really need features like "find all in current document" and "count" that notepad++ has...

Comment: @Jonathan You do get find all and count. Look at the screenshot. It highlights all and also, in the lower right of the window, you get matches which is the count.

Comment: You're right, I still found Regex Helper to be a limited tool

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ [doesn't support](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators) the alternation operator`|`.
You can try the textfx <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> regexp option but I think the same is true.

Comment: Correct regarding Scintilla RegEx functionality that is at the core of Notepad++. However, Notepad++ behavior can be modified using Plugins. Search-only or search-and-replace operations can be redirected to an external Plugin lib function. The Notepad++ PythonScript plugin supports Python Regular Expression searches and search and replace operations.  See my answer below.

Comment: The latest version as of today (Notepad 10.1.1) supports | in RegEx

Answer (score 1):

Use the [PythonScript](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) Notepad++ plugin for Python Regular Expression search function.
See [here](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/scintilla.html#Editor.pysearch) for functions

```
Editor.pysearch(expression, function[, flags[, startLine[, endLine]]])
```

or

```
Editor.pymlsearch(expression, function[, flags[, startPosition[, endPosition]]])
```

Here's a simple program using the python Regular Expression search function editor.pysearch()
I've left lots of debug code in so you can see what is happening during the course of the function run.

```
# $Revision: 1.3 $
# $Author: dot $
# $Date: 2012/04/19 00:03:26 $

from Npp import *
import re, string

expression = notepad.prompt(
                 "Enter the RegEx search string then press Enter",
                 "RegEx and Search" ,
                 "")

debug = True
#debug = False

if debug:
    bufferID = notepad.getCurrentBufferID()

if debug:
    # Show console for debugging
    console.clear()
    console.show()

if expression != None:
    expressionSansNl = expression.replace('\r\n', '')

    if debug:
        console.write( expression + "\n" )

    # First we'll start an undo action, then Ctrl-Z will undo the actions of the whole script
    editor.beginUndoAction()

    if debug:
        console.write( 'editor.pysearch( r"%s" % expressionSansNl, None)\n' )

    editor.pysearch( r"%s" % expressionSansNl, None)

    # End the undo action, so Ctrl-Z will undo the above two actions
    editor.endUndoAction()

# Debug
if debug:
    notepad.activateBufferID(bufferID)
```

Map this script to Notepad++ shortcut `Ctrl+<ChooseALetter>` and run it.
Type in search RegEx `action(421|732|983)`
According to Python re documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), the `|` RegEx operator is supported.

I haven't tested this -- maybe the None parameter in the pysearch() function needs
to be a function that will select the resulting string. According to to docs [here](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/scintilla.html#Editor.pysearch),
the function should return a python MatchObject. I think there's a way to get the
matching string from the MatchObject and select the next appearance of that matching
string in the editor object. I'll post a new revision of the answer once I'm done coding
and testing this.

Comment: This answer is for Notepad++ versions before 10.1.1. In Notepad++, the RegEx OR | operator is available.

Answer (score 0):

your regex seems to be correct. but try to use this:

```
action(421|732|983)
```

Comment: It doesn't work - I think that would find combinations of the sort of action4273283 and action4213983  ...