# Regex to find and extract lines which match filter criteria

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ 
and trying to work through a log file locally and trying to use the regex function to extract any data from the file which contains:
-1 or ?
I'm not great with the reg expressions but figured something like this would do the trick but to no avail:

```
 ^.*\b(-1|?)\b.*$
```

Comment: Which version of Notepad++ do you use. It your version is lower than 10.1.1, see my answer below

Comment: latest I see on their website is 6.1.2

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant 6.1.1. And which version you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read here:

[How do you use Notepad++ regex pipe | for strings longer than one character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820740/how-do-you-use-notepad-regex-pipe-for-strings-longer-than-one-character)

Notepad++ doesn't support pipe '|' character in its regexes in the versions lower than 6.1.1. Update your version of notepad++ and use regex:

```
^.*(\-1|[\?]).*$
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the ? character using a . I'll break it down for you so it helps you learn Regex.

```
^(.*(?:-1|\?).*)$
```

- `(?:-1|\?)` - a non capturing group that matches ? or -1
- `(.*(?:-1|\?).*)` - wrapped in a capturing group that matches anything then the ? or -1 then anything

With line boundaries this will result in a list of captured lines that contain -1 or ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
(.*-1.*|.*\?.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to find `?`, you should escape it `\?`
Second, I don't know about Notepad++ but generally `-` is not considered a word symbol and as such the firs `\b` will not work as "start of word" and should be removed, the same is for `?` which is neither start nor end of word, so for it both `\b` are useless.